# Is there any way to get the list of installable versions of a Rust crate by command?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to get the list of installable versions of a Rust crate in a script.

I want to get not the installed version but installable versions.

You can see the list of installable versions on https://crates.io .

e.g. https://crates.io/crates/skim/versions

I'd like to get the list in a script.

I checked cargo's sub commands and command line options, but I couldn't find any command and option  that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find any similar command in `cargo` documentation either. But It seems like there is an API endpoint(`/api/v1/crates/<crate_name>/versions`) available to get all the  installable versions of a `crate`.
Since you are looking for a `cargo` command, You can extend [cargo with your own custom command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-05-extending-cargo.html#extending-cargo-with-custom-commands).

> ***Extending Cargo with Custom Commands***
>
> Cargo is designed so you can
> extend it with new subcommands without having to modify Cargo. If a
> binary in your `$PATH` is named `cargo-something`, you can run it as if it
> was a Cargo subcommand by running `cargo something`. Custom commands
> like this are also listed when you run `cargo --list`. Being able to use
> `cargo install` to install extensions and then run them just like the
> built-in Cargo tools is a super convenient benefit of Cargo’s design.

To do that first create a new project:

```
$ cargo new cargo-list-installable-versions --bin
```

Please note that the project name should be of the format `cargo-YOUR_SUB_COMMAND_NAME`. Now add these two dependencies to `Cargo.toml` file.

```
reqwest = { version = "0.11.18", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
serde_json = "1.0.96"
```

Now in `main.rs` you can implement the logic to get the versions from the API endpoint `/api/v1/crates/<crate_name>/versions`.

Here is the very basic implementation.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    if let Some(package_name) = env::args().nth(2) {
        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::builder()
            .user_agent("YOUR_USER_AGENT")
            .build()
            .unwrap();
        let api_url = format!(
            "https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/{}/versions",
            package_name.trim()
        );
        let resp = client
            .get(api_url)
            .send()
            .unwrap()
            .json::<serde_json::Value>()
            .unwrap();
        if let Some(installable_versions) = resp["versions"].as_array() {
            for version in installable_versions {
                println!("{}", version["num"])
            }
        }
    } else {
        eprintln!("package name is missing")
    }
}
```

Now build & release the project. Make sure to add the release folder to the `$PATH` environment variable.

```
$ cargo build --release
$ export PATH="PATH_TO_YOUR_RELEASE_FOLDER:$PATH"
```

Now you are ready to consume your subcommand. If you configured everything correctly you can see `list-installable-versions` subcommand under `cargo --list`. To actually run it  you can use

```
$ cargo list-installable-versions <crate_name>
```

This will print all installable-versions of the `<crate_name>`.

Comment: Thanks! The API is what I want.
Where is the document about the API?